# Update Scaffold contents (appBar title and body) without pushing a new view?

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter

Say I have a main, top-level `Scaffold` with an `appBar` and and `body`.

I have a button in the appBar and in its `onTap` I do:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => new DogeWidget())
);
```

Now `DogeWidget` is also a`Scaffold`, because I like the appBar's default rendering.

What's happening:

- I see the `DogeWidget` slide from the bottom of the screen. It's a whole scaffold sliding, not just the body.

What I'd like to see:

- The main appBar's contents change, its hamburger changes into a "back arrow". There is no slide from the bottom, just an ordinary fade.

I don't know if I should write this myself or is there something that Flutter can provide?

AFAICT, the [Gallery](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_gallery) does what I want (e.g. tap on the "typography" item) - behavior is different despite my code being an almost literate copy and paste. Why?

Comment: I can't really help you with your problem, but for me at least, the Typography screen also seems to slide up from the bottom (as well as fade in). I think it starts about 20% from the top and slides into position. I am on commit `ecdfe6`.

Comment: The gallery app slides from the bottom for me too. It does not fade like the OP wanted

Answer (score 1):

For a while we had a hack that made this happen by making the AppBar a Hero, but it was not a good implementation and caused more trouble than it was worth so we backed it out. That's probably what you're seeing.

There's no easy way to do this using Navigator with today's material framework, though you can certainly implement widgets on top of the widgets layer that do it if you want to. What you might be able to do though is implement it by having a Navigator inside the `body` of your MaterialApp, and then manually replacing the AppBar (maybe via a crossfade widget like AnimatedCrossFade).

Solving this properly is something we intend to do in due course but we are prioritising bugs and API stability at the moment so it is not something we plan to do in the near term (next few months).

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to change the hamburger icon into a "back" arrow and update the app bar's title programatically? I could do the bookkeeping myself.